# objc.error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - readFromData:ofType:error: is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I am using PyObj-C and am making some methods in a python file to read and write files using `NSDocument`, which uses the abstract `NSFileCoordinater` class. Accessing files this way instead of just using python's `open` let's these classes handle things for me such as preventing files from being edited from more than one program at a time or giving enough time for read/write operations to finish before it could get deadlocked.

These features are very important, and the app I ma building I want to be up to standard as much as I can here.

I have this code that instantiates a NSDocument object that contains the content of whatever file path you put into it, as a function:

```py
@classmethod
def write(cls, file: str):
    path = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(file)
    ext = file.split('.')[-1]
    doc = NSDocument.alloc().initWithContentsOfURL_ofType_error_(path, ext, None)
```

When I call this function with a valid file path I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/user123/PycharmProjects/shoutout/src/sutils/cfiles.py", line 27, in write
    doc = NSDocument.alloc().initWithContentsOfURL_ofType_error_(path, ext, None)
objc.error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - readFromData:ofType:error: is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden.
```

I have tried to find forums both objective-c, swift, or pyobj-c based as it were asking any keywords such as `objective-c is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden` on google, and checked stackoverflow, and github for existing posts on this error but I could find none.

As I understand it Objective-C being polymorphic, has my method `initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:` call `readFromData:ofType:error`, among other ones at the same time. I don't understand exactly however what it means when it's saying that "is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden." I am not sure also about what it means to *override* a class or a one being a responsibility so that doesn't help on my part.

A [NSInternalInconsistencyException](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinternalinconsistencyexception) means a "when an internal assertion fails and implies an unexpected condition within the called code." Not sure what a internal "assertion" is either or what this could mean.

Any idea of what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

NSDocument is an abstract class that requires you to subclass and implement a number of methods to make it usable. This is document in [Apple's documentation for the class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument?language=objc).

the older [Document-Baed App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179) gives more information on this.